# Access row elements as compound list from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below, df

```
   1   2   3   4   5  6  7  8  9  10
0  C1  S1  S3
1  C2  S4  S1  S2
2  C3  S3  S5  S1 S3 
3  C4  S2  S4  S5 S2 S1 S4 S5 S6 S9  
4  C5  S1  S5
```

and another dataframe df1

```
  1   2   3   4   5    6   7    8   9  10
0  S1  1  17   6   67   0   89   0   4   7
1  S2  4  17   6   67    7   0   0   0   0
2  S3  6  89   0   4    17   6   67  0   1
3  S4  0   2   8   67    7   0   0   6   7   
4  S5  23  4   9   2     3   4   5   6   0
```

In the end,I want to access rows of the df which in turn contains values in df1 and my final data should look like below. I am aware of the `df.iloc`, but i cant append to a list.

```
C1 = [S1 appended with S3]
C1 = [ 1  17   6   67   0   89   0   4   7  6  89   0   4    17   6   67  0   1]
```

similarly ,
C2 = [ S4 S1 S2] etc.

Comment: Please improve title and formatting (have been done by @eyllanesc now) of the question. Please look to [ask] for guidelines

Answer (score 2):

***Option 1***

You can get your template lists using `apply`:

```
tmp = df.drop('0', 1).set_index('1').apply(lambda x: list(x.dropna()), 1)

1
C1        [S1, S3]
C2    [S4, S1, S2]
C3    [S3, S5, S1]
C4    [S2, S4, S5]
C5        [S1, S5]
```

Prepare `df2`:

```
df2 = df2.drop('0', 1).set_index('1')
```

Then using `loc` to explode the lists:

```
tmp.apply(lambda x: np.array([df2.loc[i] for i in x]).ravel())

1
C1    [1, 17, 6, 67, 0, 89, 0, 4, 7, 6, 89, 0, 4, 17...
C2    [0, 2, 8, 67, 7, 0, 0, 6, 7, 1, 17, 6, 67, 0, ...
C3    [6, 89, 0, 4, 17, 6, 67, 0, 1, 23, 4, 9, 2, 3,...
C4    [4, 17, 6, 67, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 67, 7, ...
C5    [1, 17, 6, 67, 0, 89, 0, 4, 7, 23, 4, 9, 2, 3,...
```

Or slightly faster using a list comprehension:

```
pd.Series([np.array([df2.loc[i] for i in x]).ravel() for x in tmp], index=tmp.index)
```

***Option 2***

```
df2 = df2.drop('0', 1).set_index('1')
dct = df2.apply(list, 1).to_dict()
tmp = df.drop('0', 1).set_index('1')
tmp.applymap(dct.get).apply(lambda x: [val for pair in x[x.notnull()] for val in pair], 1)

1
C1    [1, 17, 6, 67, 0, 89, 0, 4, 7, 6, 89, 0, 4, 17...
C2    [0, 2, 8, 67, 7, 0, 0, 6, 7, 1, 17, 6, 67, 0, ...
C3    [6, 89, 0, 4, 17, 6, 67, 0, 1, 23, 4, 9, 2, 3,...
C4    [4, 17, 6, 67, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 67, 7, ...
C5    [1, 17, 6, 67, 0, 89, 0, 4, 7, 23, 4, 9, 2, 3,...
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for the answer, but i have edited the question again, some cases have all the rows filled in that case, we cant drop a column and the first column starts with index number '1' and can you edit your answer accordingly ?? Thanks ..

Comment: Then just don't drop `0` first